What's the best way to convert the html text to hypertext on Facebook API?
I'm using a rich text editor to create social media posts' text and I save it in DB as HTML to keep the format, I want to send these texts to Facebook Graph API formatted
for example:
// DB 
<p>✨ <strong>Discover Elegance Redefined</strong>! Explore the brilliance of this meticulously crafted <em>platinum engagement ring</em>, featuring a stunning <strong>pavé diamond band</strong> that perfectly complements its breathtaking <strong>center stone</strong>.  #ForeverBrilliant #EngagementRing #LuxuryJewelry #DiamondLove ✨</p>

//FB
✨ Discover Elegance Redefined! Explore the brilliance of this meticulously crafted platinum engagement ring, featuring a stunning pavé diamond band that perfectly complements its breathtaking center stone.  #ForeverBrilliant #EngagementRing #LuxuryJewelry #DiamondLove ✨
I tried to use HTMLPurifier Library but still not working

The "ht" in "html" is literally "hypertext", so I'm unclear on that. The text you've posted appears to be markdown, or something along those lines, but I don't know if you just did that for convenience on this site. Can you post a link to specific documentation from Facebook's Graph API about the requirements?

Hi @ChrisHaas
I added these markdowns here to show how it should appear on Facebook, I want strong tag text to be bold and so on, I think there's a way in PHP to do that.

Do you want to convert HTML to markdown then? Is that what you are asking for?

Not really, I want to submit the text without markdown or HTML tags to Meta Graph API for formatted publishing.

So you want to strip all HTML from the text? Zero formatting? Nothing will be bold, italic, etc.? If that's still not correct, you will need to tell us the language or whatever that Facebook uses to describe rich text.

I found that it accepts url encoding like "dsadsada%F0%9D%98%80%F0%9D%97%B1%F0%9D%97%B1%F0%9D%97%AE%F0%9D%98%80%F0%9D%97%B1%F0%9D%97%AE%F0%9D%98%80%F0%9D%97%B1" but how to get that code from strong to these encode

Okay, the last character in the encoded string is Unicode 0x1d5f1. So the letter d that is bold is actually a mathematical symbol. I'm fairly certain that you will need a library (which I don't know if one exists) to convert ASCII to math symbols. Maybe you could write a mapping table/array, but you'd still need an HTML parser. I'm uncertain on italic characters in Unicode, too.
